2003 Honda Civic Ls overheating
My 2003 Honda Lx had the water pump,radiator done exactly a year ago due to coolent leaking. Yesterday it started to overheat cause it's been quite chilly here in the north east,so I turned my heat on and it overheated. Keep in mind,my coolant is full.No leaks. When I turn the ac on,it don't overheat. I had to drive it to the mechanic with the ac on. I just would like someone else's point of view.

Unless you can check coolant temps with a scantool/reader, the t-stat may be suspect. T-stats can fail in closed or partially open position. If the t-stat is fine then check the coolant sensor since it sends temperature signals to the engine computer to regulate cooling fan operation. A faulty coolant sensor may not detect hot coolant resulting in the ecm not turning on the cooling fan. When ac is turned on, the coolant sensor signals are bypassed since two radiators need airflow; a hot ac condenser coil in front of the hot radiator.

The engines in the 2001-2005 Honda Civic (D17) are known for overheating. The problem is the head gasket in most of these. You can replace the thermostat with an aftermarket or OEM and it will do you no good. The problem with these is that people put other than the blue Honda coolant in it and it slowly eats through head gasket and it starts leaking into the cylinder. While leaking into the cylinder, it evaporates out the tailpipe without producing white smoke ... this means it takes its time to get rid of coolant.
When this type of overheating happens, what I saw in my 2001 Civic was, the temperature gauge would spike up for a second or two, then cruise back down to a normal range. It would keep bouncing like this without giving me any other signs of an issue. I'd then top off the coolant and everything would be the normal for several days until the engine ate enough coolant.
Considering what you've said about your car not having missing coolant, I'd suggest this probably isn't the issue, but it is a possibility. More than likely your problem is one of your fans is not working. I believe there should be two fans: one for the radiator and one for the AC. If the car is only cooling when the AC is on, I'd suggest the primary fan isn't working (both draw against the radiator). Things you can check are that the primary fan is actually plugged in. Since you replaced the radiator, this is a distinct possibility. Also check to ensure that the relay for the fan is working. If the relay is bad, a temporary fix would be to swap the relays between the primary and secondary fans. This can also tell you if that is actually the issue. If that doesn't work, you may have a bad fan. You can check your fans by apply a 12v source directly to them where they connect to the wiring harness. If the primary fan doesn't run, it needs replaced. As far as what I think, I'd check the connector and make sure it is making good contact. That is most like the cause of your issue for your description.
